# Trying to print an array out of a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, fopen

I'm new here and new to C.

I want to print an array out of a file with fopen but it does not seem to work.

My empty array is `char matrix[25][25]`, and now I am trying to open a text file and print it into the array. The txt file is named `Matrix1.txt` and consists out of 625 characters that are either `'*'` or `' '`.

What I am trying to do now is:

```
//openfile(), LÄNGE=Lenght=25, BREITE=Height=25, datei=file, matrix=array
int dateiöffnen(char matrix[][LÄNGE], char* datei){

    FILE *fp;
    char cell;

    fp = fopen(datei, "r");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Fehler!\n");  //Fehler=Error
    }
    else{
        for (int y = 0; y < BREITE; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x > LÄNGE; x++){
                fscanf(fp, "%c", &cell);
                matrix[x][y] = cell;
            }
        }

        fclose(fp);
    } 
}
```

So later I try to print the array and play the Game of life with that printed array (it's in a switch):

```
case 1: 
    dateiöffnen(matrix, "Matrix1.txt");
    play(matrix); 
    print(matrix);
```

but for some reason it prints a blank array and if I try to run the openfile() in the main function like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char matrix[BREITE][LÄNGE];
    int x, y;
    //srand(time(NULL));
    dateiöffnen(matrix, "Matrix1.txt");
}
```

it prints an array like this:

[image: this]

So I am very confused and would be glad and thankful if someone could give me a hint what's going on.

Comment: One problem I can see is `for (int x = 0; x > LÄNGE; x++)` should be this `for (int x = 0; x < LÄNGE; x++)`. Could you show us the code for `print` function.

Comment: I think the *Fehler* here is that you are printing an uninitialized array!

Comment: You should be checking the return value from `fscanf()` to ensure it works.  You could also print each value as it is read, so you know what the matrix is initialized to.  But this would reveal that your matrix is not initialized because of the bug in the inner loop — there'd be no printing.  Printing the data as it is read is a basic mechanism for checking whether the I/O is working as you expect — something you should check automatically if (when) things aren't working as you think they should.

Comment: In general, I would wonder about portability when using umlauts, and maybe also about maintainability with only non-English comments. Not a problem with personal projects, but maybe a good habit to get into? Here in Germany, we professionals always write our comments only in English, and a German comment won't get through code review

Comment: yes as said, i'm really new and when i started this project i just worte all comments in german, I'm gonna do better next time. I changed all the umlauts.

I have an initialising functing 
edit: i pressed enter by accident

int init_matrix(char matrix[][LAENGE]) {

 int x, y;

 for (x = 0; x < BREITE; x++){

  for (y = 0; y < LAENGE; y++){

   matrix[x][y] = 0;

  }
 }
 return matrix;
}

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a typo in the inner for loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x > LÄNGE; x++){
```

should be:

```
for (int x = 0; x < LÄNGE; x++){
```